# What is sum of squared elements of Farey sequence?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, diophantine-approximation, farey-sequences

Let's consider a Farey sequence:
$$F_{n}=\{a_{1},...,a_{k}\}$$;

Where given elements satisfy definition of $n$-th Farey sequence.

My problem: Find the formula for the following sum:
$$\sum_{l=1}^{k}a_{l}^{2}=?$$
Alternatively find asymptotic growth in dependence of $n$.

Only thing i know is that denominator of this sum is $(n!)^{2}$.

Regards.

Comment: Solution in http://www.iosrjournals.org/iosr-jm/papers/Vol12-issue2/Version-6/H1202064547.pdf

Comment: Sorry, but i asked for sum of squares Farey elements not squared sum of Farey elements.

Comment: I don't understand : the article gives a method for the sum of the squares of a Farey sequence...

Comment: Yes, it basically says: If you want to calculate the sum of squares of the elements of a Farey sequence, you have to add the squares of the elements of the Farey sequence.

Comment: By the way, confirming the currently assumed asymptotic growth would prove the Riemann hypothesis. [Farey sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence)